# How to hash generic key in generic hash table implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, function, generics, hash

I'm implementing hash table using generics, like Dictionary implemented in c#, but I'm stuck in Hash function part. I successufuly rewritten non-generic implementation of Hash table in generic one but you will notice in code that I have no idea how to hash Tkey.

```
class Node<T, U>
{
    public T key;
    public U value;
    public Node<T, U> next;
    public Node(T key, U value, Node<T, U> next)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
 }

public  class HashTable<T,U>
{
    int length;
    Node<T,U>[] buckets;
    public HashTable(int length)
    {
        this.length = length;
        buckets = new Node<T,U>[length];
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        for (int bucket = 0; bucket<buckets.Length; bucket++)
        {
            Node<T,U> current = buckets[bucket];
            Console.Write(bucket + ":");
            while (current != null)
            {
                Console.Write("["+current.key+","+current.value+"]");
                current=current.next;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
     //  private int Hash(T Tkey) ...
    //// non-generic version of hash function

    private int Hash(string str)
    {
        int h=0;
        foreach(var s in str)
            h=127*h+s;
        return h%length;

    }
     ////
    public void Insert(T key, U value)
    {
        int bucket = Hash(key);
        buckets[bucket] = new Node<T,U>(key, value, buckets[bucket]);
    }
    public U Search(T key)
    {
        Node<T,U> current = buckets[Hash(key)];
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.key.Equals(key))
                return current.value;
            current= current.next;
        }
        throw new Exception(key+ "Not found");
    }
```

Comment: Is this [tag:java]? If so, please tag appropriately.

Comment: *Why* are you writing you own implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base object class in C# comes with the [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method which should be used for these situations.

Some classes come with a good implementation, others just inherit the method from `System.Object` and do not override it.

From the MSDN documentation:

The default implementation of the `GetHashCode` method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects. Furthermore, the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the `GetHashCode` method, and the value it returns will be the same between different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes.

The `GetHashCode` method can be overridden by a derived type. Value types must override this method to provide a hash function that is appropriate for that type and to provide a useful distribution in a hash table. For uniqueness, the hash code must be based on the value of an instance field or property instead of a static field or property.

Comment: I suppose I should write my own Hash function. First of all, GetHashCode is not guaranteed to produce the same behaviour between versions. Also GetHashCode can return negative value, so I get Index out of bounds error. However, if I wrote: return Math.Abs(Tkey.GetHashCode()); inside my  Hash function I have some output but I suppose this is stupid solution. The idea of hashing should be reducing the likelihood of collisions but I'm not sure what I get with this.

Comment: You should really use GetHashCode; it is up to the dependent object to determine whether the object returns the same hash or not.  Just because it doesn't work with your scheme shouldn't matter; adjust the value as you need to to fit your requirements, but do so consistently.

Comment: @impeRAtoR, why would you need same behavior between versions? And using `Math.Abs()` here is not stupid at all. `Dictionary` does something very similar.

Comment: @impeRAtoR: If it matters to you that `GetHashCode` is consistent across platforms, you're doing it wrong. If you care that `GetHashCode` returns negative values, you're doing it wrong. `GetHashCode` is for producing values that can be used for balancing hash tables. They are not intended for any  other purpose, so do not use them as such.

Comment: @Bruno, what do you mean by “others just extend `System.Object`”? Do you mean that they use the implementation of `GetHashCode()` provided by `object`?

Comment: @svick, some classes do not override `GetHashCode()` so they inherit the implementation provided by `object`.

Comment: @BrunoSilva, yeah, but that's not what you said. That's why I am confused. You are talking about some “extending” of `object`, which doesn't make sense here at all.

Comment: Technically, you're right that the implementation from `object` does not guarantee unique values. But that's just because most implementations of `GetHashCode` don't either. How could you guarantee that two different strings have different hash codes, when there is much more `string`s than there is `int`s?

Comment: You can't guarantee it, that's why it is a hash function :)