# Indexing generic hash table/dictionary by attribute in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to index a generic hash table containing type T such that for every instance t of T in the table, t is indexed by the attribute a of t?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a Dictionary.Keys Key through a numeric index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227/accessing-a-dictionary-keys-key-through-a-numeric-index)

Comment: Couldn't understand. Plus, is the T a custom class or?
@TMartin He wants to access the element by one of its attributes, not by numeric index.

Comment: Why not make a second dictionary for that other "attribute"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353982/how-to-hash-generic-key-in-generic-hash-table-implementation?rq=1, override the `GetHashCode` function to have it "indexed by the attribute a of t"

Comment: You can just use `myCollection.ElementAt(Array.FindIndex(myCollection.ToArray(), x => x.Property = whatIWantToCheck))`, but it's a bit of overkill tho. As the person above me said, why don't you just use the property as a key for your dictionary?